# Assembly 8086: Two Float Point[32bit] Adding,Sub etc

Tags: assembly, floating-point, 32-bit, x86-16

I need add two float point in 8086

```
    12.3 ---> 4144 CCCDh
    (AX,BX) = (4144h, CCCDh)
```

I need add any number this float point look like:

```
    (AX,BX) = (AX,BX) + 10h
```

if i do that answer is wrong.

```
     (AX,BX) + 10h == 4144 CCECh
```

but 23,3 didnt equal to 4144 CCECh

Can you help me? How i adding this two number?

Comment: Do you really have an 8086? If so, an 8087 as well? That would do floating point a lot better. Anyway, please show us some of your code.

Comment: I am new in asembly, i use emu 8086 for coding. This my quiz question i dont how i add this two number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't verified this (especially the offset in bp), but it should give some perspective.
It uses the ancient [8087 floating point instruction set](http://www.intel-assembler.it/portale/5/The-8087-Instruction-Set/A-one-line-description-of-x87-instructions.asp).

All operations happen inbetween coprocessor stack and/or memory. Integers can be converted from 2's complement representation using instruction `FILD mem` and in some cases there's a built in addition instruction that adds integer (from memory) to FP register.

```
 push bp
 mov bp, sp
 push bx
 push ax
 push word ptr 10   ;  // decimal, not hex
 fld dword ptr [bp] ;   load float (just pushed from bx,ax)
 fiadd word ptr [bp-4] ;   add the integer in stack
 fst dword ptr [bp] ;   store result
 pop ax             
 pop ax             ; restore the high word of result
 pop bx             ; restore low word
 pop bp             ; restore frame pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an integer (10) to an IEEE-754 float value (12.3f = 0x4144cccd) like that. You need to express 10 in IEEE-754 format (10.0f = 0x41200000) and then use a floating point addition instruction.

```
  0x4144cccd      12.3
+ 0x41200000    + 10.0
  ----------      ----
  0x41B26666      22.3
```

Comment: thanks but how i give this value to register in 8086 can u help ?

Comment: If it's really an ancient 8086 then you need an 8087 co-processor or a software FPU emulation. Either that or you'll have to write some floating point routines yourself.